# Why to declare ioexception when numberformatexception occurring?

Tags: java

```
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    str = br.readLine();
    i = Integer.parseInt(str);
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.Println("enter a valid input");
}
```

When I try to compile this code it throws a compile error that ioexception is occuring I should catch it.

Therefore I have to add a `catch(IOException e)` statement, but the exception  that occurs is a number format exception of `java.lang` library so why do I have to catch `ioException`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
str=br.readLine();
```

[**BufferedReader.readLine()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) throws **IOException**.

```
public String readLine() throws IOException
```

> Throws: IOException - If an I/O error occurs

as **IOException** is a checked exception you either need to handle it using try/catch block  or declare it using throws clause.

```
try
{
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
str=br.readLine();
i=Integer.parseInt(str);
}catch(IOException e)
{System.out.println("IOException occured... " + e.printStacktrace());
catch(NumberFormatException e)
{System.out.println("enter a valid input");
}
```

**In java 7 Multiple catch:**

```
try
    {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    str=br.readLine();
    i=Integer.parseInt(str);
    }
catch(IOException | NumberFormatException ex) {
System.out.println(ex.printStackTrace())
}
```

Comment: so the program should work even if i handle only ioexception but if i do that then the program throws a runtime error when i enter anything other than a integer

Comment: @shankisam912 NumberFormatException is an unchecked runtime exception. compiler will not force you to handle RunTimeException. where as IOException is a checked Exception. i.e., if a piece of code is prone to throw unchecked Exception compiler will force you to handle it.

Comment: @shankisam912 yes. check the API. br.read() throws IOException as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

**[`BufferedReader.readLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29)** can throw an `IOException` in case an I/O error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

beacuse this line str=br.readLine(); may be occur the IOException

Answer (score 0):

It is because,

```
bufferedReader.readLine ()
```

throws IOException which is a checked exception. All the checked exceptions should be with in a try catch block. You can either catch IOException or generic Exception. The code snippet is given below. Also NumberFormatException is a runtime exception. You don't need to catch it unless it is required.

```
try {
     String str = bufferedReader.readLine ();
} catch (IOException ie) {
     ie.printStacktrace();
}


try {
     String str = bufferedReader.readLine ();
} catch (Exception ie) {
     e.printStacktrace();
}
```